# "Будучи" й "бувши". Перше - неправильне?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова, помилки

[LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/uk/) в ґуґл-докс сказав мені отаке:

`будучи - помилкове слово, виправлення: бувши.`

На [російсько-українських словниках](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5380) це підтверджують.

Питання:

Якщо це правда, чому [словники України онлайн](https://snag.gy/VB081Q.jpg) дають цю форму дієприслівника, як одну з можливих?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Не стовідсоткова надійність «Словників України on-line»

«Словники України on-line» створювалися в напівавтоматичному режимі і містять певну кількість помилок (див. розділ [«Неточності електронної лексикографічної системи» в статті про «Словники України on-line» в українській Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8_on-line#.D0.9D.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.96_.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.97_.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.84.D1.96.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.97_.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B8)).

Хоча зараз більшість помилок виправлена, поодинокі все ще трапляються. Наприклад, *Янисъярві* (sic! з російським твердим знаком) — в українській Вікіпедії навіть є стаття [Янисъярві](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%96), що перенаправляє на вищеназваний розділ.

Якби інші словники «будучи» не містили — то це можна було б вважати ще однією помилкою «Словників України on-line». При цьому, як підказала Oksana Gubrenko, слід перевіряти наявність цього слова не лише в головному переліку слів, а й у статті про дієслово «бути», формою якого може бути дієприслівник «будучи». Крім того, словники не зобов'язані перелічувати всі форми — відсутність згадок про слово «будучи» у словнику, що не наводить дієприслівники й для інших дієслів, не є аргументом проти «будучи».

#### За існування «будучи»

Тлумачний «Словник української мови» в 20 томах 2010-х років (що теж, як і «Словники україни on-line», створювався під егідою Національної академії наук України), хоча й не містить статті про слово «будучи» (але й не зобов'язаний містити, це лише форма; до речі, містить статтю «[будучий](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=5801&page=215)»), проте [згадує його в прикладах](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8+site:http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/&filter=0):

- Для мене нема в тім нічого лякаючого бачити, як хтось вправляється в спорті, котрим я, будучи ще академіком, займався досхочу (О. Кобилянська);
- Будучи свого часу учнем Вольтера, К. А. Гельвецій критично ставився до його деїстичних поглядів і повністю відійшов від ідеалізму (з наук. літ.);
- Ягор, спродавши якось у місті багатющий урожай полуниці і добре будучи під джмелем, на весь виторг найняв духовий оркестр, — до самої Зачіплянки грали
  (О. Гончар).

«Словарь росийсько-український» Уманця і Спілки (1893–1898), хоча й не містить статті про слово «будучи», [згадує його в прикладах](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8&scope=ukrq&dicts=9&highlight=on):

- Чого ми вдячни от них будучи. <sub>//Статутъ великого князства Литовского. (Після видання 1599 року.) Москва. 1858.</sub>
- Будучи возним, маю позви і всякії листи врядовиє справедливо і пильно отдавати. <sub>//Звідти ж.</sub>
- Притиснені будучи тяжаром сил. <sub>//Словарь малороссійскихъ идіомовъ или собраніе словъ несходныхъ съ русскими. Составилъ Н. Закревскій. М. 1860. Старосвѣтский бандуриста. Ст. 247–628—8°. (*[Коментар Уманця і Спілки:]* Всїх слів 11,127, слова всї певні, але значеня їх часто переказано не вірно.)</sub>
- А дїточки, яко немовлятки будучи, того не знають. //Богословїѧ нравоꙋ҆читεлнаѧ. Ти́помъ Братства при Цέркви Хра́ма Ѹспὲнїѧ прεст҃ы́ѧ Вл҃чици на́шεѧ Бц҃ы. Въ Лвовѣ. Ро́кꙋ ҂ѱѯ (1760).
- Вдова, винна будучи до скриньки міської грошей. <sub>//Кіевская Старина. Ежемѣсячный историческій журналъ. К.</sub>

Також «будучи» [згадується](//books.google.com/books?id=fQkLAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8) в журналі «Мовознавство» 2006 року видання «Наукова думка» (знов таки НАНУ) — хоча й не знаю в якому контексті, але там є принаймні дві цитати зі словом «будучи» і якийсь перелік посилань:

> *бу́дучи* (Остр. зб., 29 зв., ЗО зв., 32, 33, 47 зв., 160 зв.; С. Зиз., 49, 73, 76, 83, 86, 89, 97, 101 <…>

— тож можна припустити, що вони, якщо навіть не є повними прихильниками позиції про існування слова, то принаймні всерйоз розглядають таку можливіть.

Також «будучи» використовується:

- Чотири рази в [журналі «Русалка» від 1 січня 1866](//books.google.com/books?id=56pjZraDnAUC&pg=PA69&dq=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8), Львів (ст. 30, 69) — в українських текстах.
- Тричі в якійсь [книзі майже без реквізитів 1907 року видання](//books.google.com/books?id=0g7UAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8), причому перші два вжитки (ст. 196, 278) — явно в українських текстах.
- Безліч разів у «[Літописі Самійла Величка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)».
- Безліч разів у сучасній літературі.

#### Нейтральне

- <sub>«Будучи» є словом-паразитом, яке багаторазово використовує Шельменко, головний персонаж комедій [«Шельменко-денщик»](http://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=2451) (в іншому виданні: [«Шельменко-наймит»](//books.google.com/books?id=wD5dAAAAcAAJ)) і [«Шельменко. Волостной писарь»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Kvitka-Osnovianenko/Shelmenko_Volostnoi_pysar/) Григорія Квітки-Основ'яненка, але герої не зобов'язані говорити абсолютно правильною мовою — і справді, в цих повістях використовується і українська, і російська, і суржик.</sub>
- <sub>Слово згадується в книзі Івана Слинько «Історичний синтаксис української мови» ([ст. 15, 36, 43](//books.google.com/books?id=bYA-AQAAIAAJ&q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8)) — але незрозуміло, в якому констексті (можливо, якраз як слово, що вийшло чи виходить з мови).</sub>
- <sub>Радянський «Словник української мови» в 11 томах 1970-х–1980-х років так само, як і його сучасний наступник у 20 томах, не містить статті «будучи», але [багато вживає його в цитатах](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8+site:sum.in.ua&filter=0) (і містить статтю «[будучий](http://sum.in.ua/s/buduchyj)») — причому згадок навіть більше, ніж у сучасному словнику (навіть урахувуючи неповну доступність сучасного словника і беручи лише спільні статті, ми бачимо, що вживань поменшмало). Що теоретично, може бути й аргументом «проти», бо зменшення вжитку слова у словниках може відбивати зменшенення справжнього вжитку.</sub>

#### Висновки

З усього вищезазначеного здається, що слово існує. Але наскільки його використання доречне, мені сказати важко. Можливо, воно є неоптимальним або його фактичне використання зменшується — я не намагався перевірити це.

Comment: "Якщо інші словники «будучи» не містять, то, можливо, це є помилкою." <=  Якщо я правильно пам'ятаю, словникові статті укладаються для частин мови, а дієприслівник і дієприкметник такими не є, це лиш форми дієслова.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, Ви праві, я занадто розбестився інтернет-словниками, де вводиш у будь-якій формі, а воно перенаправляє на головну. Треба з урахуванням цього виправити відповідь. СУМ-20 містить «будучи» принаймні в цититах: [академік](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=633&page=27), [деїстичний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21333&page=722), [джміль](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=21919&page=1301).

Comment: @Sasha Чи можна констатувати відсутність українських онлайн-джерел зі 100% надійністю?

Comment: @P.Vovk, не зовсім зрозумів. Який джерел? Що згадують це слово? То ж я, навпаки, наводив джерела, що його згадують.

Comment: @Sasha взагалі. Назвіть хоч одне джерело, якому можна довіряти на 100%.

Comment: @P.Vovk, ааа. Ви мали на увазі _джерела_ зі 100% надійністю. Я спочатку подумав, що Ви маєте на увазі _констатувати відсутність_ зі 100% надійністю.

Comment: @P.Vovk, ну це залежить від того, що Ви маєте на увазі під 100% надійністю. Як на мене, жодний словник не має 100% надійності, він лише констатує вжитки слів у літературі чи живій мові постфактум, я би більше дивився на те, як вживали це слово письменники. Кобилянська вважається класиком і Кобилянська вживала. Якщо ж Ви хочете доказ із грифов НАНУ, то тут я би спирався на «Словники України on-line» — за винятком випадків очевидних помилок я би довіряв цьому словнику. Але зі 100% впевненістю нічого сказати не можу.

Comment: @P.Vovk, о, і Шевченко вживав: «Саул, не будучи дурак, Набрав гарем собі чималий Та й заходився царювать», і Куліш вживав: «Ти, пане полковнику ніженський, і всі, під його рукою будучи, послухайте мого голосу, не погубляйте отчизни».

Comment: @Sasha дякую, мені дуже подобається ваша відповідь в цілому і коментарі.

Comment: @P.Vovk, я вже продовжу, бо почав шукати: Леся Українка, Максим Рильський, Олесь Гончар, Григорій Епік, Іван Багмут, Іван Цюпа, Степан Олійник, Юрій Смолич, Семен Журахович, Іван Гончаренко, Іван Ле — вживали (багато з цих імен я не знаю, але перші три…). І самі автори СУМ-11 постійно вживали це слово не лише в цитатах, а і, як виявилося, в означеннях.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64132/discussion-between-p-vovk-and-sasha).

Answer (score 3):

[Український правопис. — К.: Наукова думка, 2015.](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par83)

> **§ 85. ДІЄПРИСЛІВНИК**
>
> 1. **Дієприслівники теперішнього часу** утворюються від основи дієслова теперішнього часу за допомогою суфіксів **`-учи`**
>      **`(-ючи)`**, **`-ачи`** **`(-ячи)`**. Суфікс **`-учи (-ючи)`** виступає **в дієприслівниках, утворених від дієслів першої
>      дієвідміни**, а суфікс **`-ачи (-ячи)`** — **в дієприслівниках,
>      утворених від дієслів другої дієвідміни**: б*еруть — беручи,
>      виробляють — виробляючи, ідуть — ідучи, кажуть — кажучи; бачать —
>      бачачи, летять — летячи, сидять — сидячи, сплять — сплячи*.
> 2. **Дієприслівники минулого часу** утворюються від основи дієслова минулого часу чоловічого роду за допомогою суфікса **`-ши`** (після
>      основи на приголосний) і **`-вши`** (після основи на голосний): *брав
>      — бравши, купував — купувавши, купив — купивши, налетів — налетівши;
>      приніс — принісши, спік — спікши, став — ставши*.

[І.П.Ющук. Практикум з правопису і граматики української мови. Посібник.](https://ushchuk.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/d196.pdf)

> **§ 91. Творення і вживання дієприслівників**
>
> Дієприслівник означає другорядну дію порівняно з основною дією того
>   самого предмета: *Відпочиваючи, читаю.*
>
> **Дієприслівники бувають недоконаного і доконаного виду. Час у них не
>   визначаємо.**
>
> **1. Дієприслівники недоконаного виду (що роблячи? ) називають дію, одночасну з основною дією**.
>
> Вони творяться від теперішнього часу дієслова за допомогою суфіксів
>   **`-учи`** (на письмі ще **–ючи**) для І дієвідміни і **`-ачи`** (**`-ячи`**) для II дієвідміни. Для цього досить дієслово поставити в
>   3-й особі множини теперішнього часу (що роблять? ) і -ть замінити на
>   -чи (пор. § 81.2): *несуть — несучи, борються — борючись, гуркотять — гуркотячи*.
>
> <...>
>
> 2. У кінці дієприслівників завжди пишеться буква и. Дієприслівники треба відрізняти від близьких за звучанням активних дієприкметників у
>      називному відмінку множини, які на відміну від дієприслівників мають
>      закінчення -і: дієприслівники відповідають на питання що роблячи?
>      (сяючи, ревучи, сидячи), дієприкметники—на питання які? (сяючі,
>      ревучі, сидячі).
>
> <...>
>
> **3. Дієприслівники доконаного виду (що зробивши? ) називають дію,яка передує основній дії:** *Відпочивши, читаю.*
>
> Вони творяться від минулого часу дієслова доконаного виду (що зробив?)
>   за допомогою суфікса **`-ши`**: *сказав — сказавши, приніс — принісши,
>   переміг — перемігши*. У кінці цих дієприслівників теж завжди пишеться
>   буква и.
>
> <...>
>
> 4. Дієприслівник можна вживати лише тоді, коли в реченні до одного діяча відноситься щонайменше дві дії. У такому разі дієприслівником
>      позначають менш важливу, другорядну дію.
>
> Наприклад, не можна вжити дієприслівник в реченні *Коли в грядуще
>   дивимось сьогодні, нам уявляються лави молоді*, бо тут кожна дія
>   стосується іншого діяча: дивимось — ми, а уявляються (хто? щ о?) —
>   лави. І навпаки, в реченні *Коли в грядуще дивимось сьогодні, бачим
>   лави молоді* можна вжити дієприслівник, бо обидві дії стосуються того
>   самого діяча ми — ми дивимось і ми бачим: *В грядуще дивлячись
>   сьогодні, ми бачим лави молоді...* (М.Нагнибіда.)

Попри те, що професор Ющук вважає, що дієприслівники не розрізняються за часом, а тільки за видом, в обох джерелах відсутні будь-які застереження щодо існування дієприслівника `будучи` (чи то теперішнього часу, чи недоконаного виду).

P.S. Можливо, LanguageTool в ґуґл-докс вказав на помилку, з огляду часової (видової) неузгодженості (треба дивитися речення).

P.P.S. Цікаво, що у статті "Росіянизм" на ресурсі [Wikiwand](http://www.wikiwand.com/uk/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC) дієприслівник `будучи` вжито чотири рази.

Comment: Дякую. Знов мене плутають українські інтернет-ресурси.

Comment: @P.Vovk, зізнаюсь, і сама почасти піддаюсь натиску пуристів. Це ж стосується і *будучи*. Наприклад, замінювала "Компанія, будучи акціонером товариства, має право на отримання дивідендів." на "Компанія, як аціонер Товариства, має право на отримання дивідендів". Тепер от думаю)

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, безвідносно до того, чи є таке слово (а, здається, є), формулювання «компанія, як акціонер товариства» мені подобається значно більше.